# Cannot register two nodes to selenium/hub while network_mode is "host" in docker-compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, selenium-grid

I'm trying to build a local selenium/hub to access my local development site and it's working fine but only with a single node. With two or more nodes I'm getting the following error (only one node is registered):

> web-automation_chrome | 19:27:27.120 ERROR [BaseServer.start] - Port
> 5555 is busy, please choose a free port and specify it using -port
> option web-automation_chrome | Exception in thread "main"
> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.BindException: Address already in
> use

The problem is that we cannot play with ports if use ***network_mode: host***.
Do you have any idea how to handle this issue?

Here is the content of docker-compose file:

```
services:

  hub:
    image: selenium/hub
    network_mode: "host"
    environment:
      GRID_MAX_SESSION: 16
      GRID_BROWSER_TIMEOUT: 3000
      GRID_TIMEOUT: 3000

  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome
    container_name: web-automation_chrome
    depends_on:
      - hub
    network_mode: "host" 
    environment:
      HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR: localhost 
      HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT: 4444
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm

  firefox:
    image: selenium/node-firefox
    container_name: web-automation_firefox
    depends_on:
      - hub
    network_mode: "host"
    environment:
      HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR: localhost 
      HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT: 4444
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
```

Comment: `network_mode: host` generally disables Docker's networking stack, and it should almost never be necessary.  Is there a reason you have it here?

Comment: The reason is that the flask app is running on localhost and without `network_mode: host` the page is not reachable in selenium grid container. Here is the picture with details: [image](https://imgur.com/UGQlL9u). So basically I want to make localhost:8080 reachable in selenium grid container.